# Openlayers WFS events: click or hover functionality not registering

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I've successfully gotten this to work before so I am confused as to why it's not working this time. Everything seems to be in place: no mapfile errors, no js errors in the console.

Here's a gist of the js: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7664194

Lines 177-217 being the ones of concern.

Note: the points are displaying correctly, but I just can't get any events to register on the points, whether it be hover or click.

```
var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("SW Airports", {
            wrapDateLine: true,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    srsName: "EPSG:3857",
                    version: "1.0.0",
                    url: "http://another_server/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/tmp/navhome/navcore/interactive/interactive_viewer.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&srsName=EPSG:3857",
                    featureType: "Airports"
            })
    });
map.addLayer(wfs);

var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
            [wfs],
            {
                    clickout: true, toggle: true,
                    multiple: true, hover: true,
                    toggleKey: "ctrlKey",
                    multipleKey: "shiftKey"
            }
    );

    map.addControl(selectControl);
    selectControl.activate();

    wfs.events.on({
    featureselected: function(event) {
            var feature = event.feature;
            feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("box",
                    feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                    null,
                    '<div>Airport: '+feature.attributes.name +'<br> IATA: '+feature.attributes.iata+'<br>'+'</div>'+ '<a href="#" onclick="jump('+feature.attributes.lat+', '+ feature.attributes.long+')">Center on Location</a>'+ '<br>'+'<a href="#" onclick="jump_to_max_zoom('+feature.attributes.lat+', '+ feature.attributes.long+')">Center on Location and Zoom In</a>',
                    null,
                    true
            );
            while( map.popups.length ) {
                    map.removePopup( map.popups[0] );
            }
            map.addPopup(feature.popup);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the issue was I had two

`new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature`

which I don't think is possible. So I just added the new layer into the initial one and all is fine.